# TensorFlow Servering returns incorrect results

Tags: tensorflow, keras, grpc, torch, tensorflow-serving

I have 2 different models (Model A is Keras .h5 and Model B is Torch .pth). They need to be served with TFServing. I converted both of these models to Tensorflow (with index .pb) for serving.
I succeeded to serve and get the outputs, but when I compared serving results with the straight model's outputs (on Keras and Torch model), I found that it had made wrong results. The prediction's score for the same image on the server-side is more unreliable than in model output. I could not understand, whether it raises from faults in model converting or anything else?
How could I fix it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The reason of different results is due to different default parameters of layers and optimizer. For example in pytorch decay-rate of batch-norm is considered as 0.9, whereas in keras it is 0.99. Like that, there may be other variation in default parameters.

I would also recommend to check the weight initializations, as they might be different between both frameworks. Thank you!